# Parse cloud code beforeSave fail to ensure records are unique

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Attendance", function (request, response) {
    var Attendance = Parse.Object.extend("Attendance");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Attendance);
    query.equalTo('user', { "__type": "Pointer", "className": "_User", "objectId": request.object.get("user").id });
    query.equalTo('meeting', { "__type": "Pointer", "className": "Meeting", "objectId": request.object.get("meeting").id });
    query.first({ useMasterKey: true }).then(function (result) {
        if (result == undefined) {
            console.log("!!!!!!!!! attendance creation approved for user id " + request.object.get("user").id + " and meeting id " + request.object.get("meeting").id)
            response.success();
        } else {
            response.error("Attendance creation prevented because same attendance with same owner and meeting already exists")
        }
    }, function (err) {
        console.error(err);
        response.error(err);
        return;
    });
});
```

I have an Attendance class with two columns: user pointer and meeting pointer.
Every user should only have one Attendance record in one meeting.
So in the beforeSave cloud code trigger, I do a query to see if an existing Attendance record exist. I thought this will prevent duplicated Attendance record.

But when we simulate large number of concurrent requests, e.g. creating 50 duplicated Attendance records in a for loop, we still see large number, like 33 duplicated records, being created.

This feels like a race condition.

How can we truly prevent duplicated objects like this?

Answer (score 1):

I would add a unique index to the "Attendance" collection.

```
db.collection.createIndex({'_p_user':1,'_p_meeting':1}, { unique: true } )
```

This way mongo handles the uniqueness and no query is required (error 137 will be thrown).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you shouldn't manually write a parse object for comparison. Try this way:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Attendance", function (request, response) {
    var Attendance = Parse.Object.extend("Attendance");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Attendance);
    query.equalTo('user', request.object.get("user"));
    query.equalTo('meeting', request.object.get("meeting"));
    query.first({ useMasterKey: true }).then(function (result) {
        if (!result) {
            console.log("!!!!!!!!! attendance creation approved for user id " + request.object.get("user").id + " and meeting id " + request.object.get("meeting").id)
            response.success();
        } else {
            response.error("Attendance creation prevented because same attendance with same owner and meeting already exists")
        }
    }, function (err) {
        console.error(err);
        response.error(err);
        return;
    });
});
```